# Privacy error when viewing files in DigitalOcean Spaces?

Tags: digital-ocean-spaces

I set up a Spaces volume and uploaded a couple images via the DigitalOcean UI. When I attempt to view the images, I get a Privacy Error page in Chrome, with `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. I'm having a hard time finding any relevant help from Google; any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out I used a `.` in the name of the Spaces volume, which was the cause of the issue.